# Change the background color of the draggable allotment pane

Tags: css, reactjs, panel

I have made a draggable split panel by https://github.com/johnwalley/allotment.

I would like to make the background of the pane below `green`. But after dragging the split, the background color is not systematically updated in that area.

Does anyone know how to amend the code to achieve that?

https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-forked-rfifun?file=/src/App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Allotment } from "allotment";
import "allotment/dist/style.css";
import styles from "./App.module.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      toExpand: true
    };
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }

  handleChange = (sizes) => {
    if (sizes.length > 1) {
      if (sizes[1] < 31) {
        this.setState({ toExpand: true });
      } else {
        this.setState({ toExpand: false });
      }
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className={styles.container}>
          <Allotment vertical onChange={this.handleChange} ref={this.myRef}>
            <Allotment.Pane>Main Area</Allotment.Pane>
            <Allotment.Pane preferredSize="0%">
              <div
                style={{ backgroundColor: "green" }}
                onClick={() => {
                  if (this.state.toExpand) {
                    this.myRef.current.resize([50, 50]);
                  } else {
                    this.myRef.current.resize([10000, 0]);
                  }
                }}
              >
                Console &nbsp;
                {this.state.toExpand ? "ArrowUp" : "ArrowDown"}
              </div>
            </Allotment.Pane>
          </Allotment>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the content `div` can be set to take full height of the panel:

Forked demo with modification: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-forked-906yrx?file=/src/App.js)

```
<Allotment.Pane preferredSize="0%">
  <div
    //  Set the content div to take full height
    style={{ backgroundColor: "green", height: "100%" }}
    onClick={() => {
      if (this.state.toExpand) {
        this.myRef.current.resize([50, 50]);
      } else {
        this.myRef.current.resize([10000, 0]);
      }
    }}
  >
    Console &nbsp;
    {this.state.toExpand ? "ArrowUp" : "ArrowDown"}
  </div>
</Allotment.Pane>;
```